# How do you set a focus on JTextField in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, focus

I created a form using Swing in Java. In the form I have used a `JTextField` on which I have to set the focus whenever I press a key. How do I set focus on a particular component in Swing?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Would [`Component.requestFocus()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus()) give you what you need?

Comment: FYI, the [javadocs for JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) say of `requestFocus()`, "use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow()). If you would like more information on focus, see [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), a section in The Java Tutorial."

Answer (score 31):

***This would work..***

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() { 

public void run() { 
        Component.requestFocus(); 
    } 
} );
```

Comment: This one works for me, unlike the others, especially since I'm switching from one screen to another in my app, and requesting the focus when the new screen opens.

Answer (score 16):

Now that we've searched the API all we need to do is read the API.

According to the API documentation:

> "Because the focus behavior of this
>   method is platform-dependent,
>   developers are strongly encouraged to
>   use requestFocusInWindow when
>   possible. "

Answer (score 6):

Note that all of the above fails for some reason in a JOptionPane.  After much trial and error (more than the above stated 5 minutes, anyway), here is what finally worked:

```
        final JTextField usernameField = new JTextField();
// ...
        usernameField.addAncestorListener(new RequestFocusListener());
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, panel, "Credentials", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);


public class RequestFocusListener implements AncestorListener {
    @Override
    public void ancestorAdded(final AncestorEvent e) {
        final AncestorListener al = this;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JComponent component = e.getComponent();
                component.requestFocusInWindow();
                component.removeAncestorListener(al);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorMoved(final AncestorEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorRemoved(final AncestorEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use also `JComponent.grabFocus();` it is the same

Comment: Javadoc for [JComponent.grabFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#grabFocus--) explicitly states that this method should not be used by the client code and suggests to use `requestFocusInWindow()` method, which is already mentioned in other answers.