# How to edit JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

I want to write a simple Swing application with a button and a text field at the bottom. I'm using a `JTextField` but it is not clickable. I searched on the web and SO, but I could not find a solution. In question [How to Set Focus on JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723257/how-to-set-focus-on-jtextfield), I found the following :

```
addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened( WindowEvent e ){
            entry.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

but this does not help. In this other question ([How do you set a focus on Textfield in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425392/how-do-you-set-a-focus-on-textfield-in-swing)) I found `Component.requestFocus()` but this does not work either. I also tried

```
    entry.setFocusable(true);
    entry.setEditable(true);
    entry.setEnabled(true);
```

without effects. My code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StackSample extends JFrame {

    public StackSample() {
        initUI();
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton buttonDraw = new JButton("Draw");
        bottomPanel.add(buttonDraw);
        JTextField entry = new JTextField();
        bottomPanel.add(entry);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8359448221778584189L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyApp app = new MyApp();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JTextField is clickable. The only problem is that it's too small.

This is because you're using FlowLayout, which will make components as small as possible.

One solution is to simply switch to a layout that allows components to fill as much space as possible, such as BoxLayout:

```
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Comment: bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); helps; obviously should be "StackSample app = new StackSample();"

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a size for your JTextField, so it defaults to zero characters wide. Try using the constructor that specifies the number of columns.

Also, what is MyApp? I can't see any evidence that your StackSample is ever created or used.