# focusing on a textfield in a panel which is in a tabbed pane that contains many panels

Tags: java, user-interface, barcode, barcode-scanner, netbeans-8

I am working on a barcode application which has in its main **GUI** a tabbed pane that contains many panels where one of this panels is for the cashier, the problem is that when the cashier panel is displayed i need to always set focus on the textfield where the barcode must be inserted.
`requestFocusInWindow()` or `requestFocus()` does not work since I am in the same `jframe` and in the same `jTabbedPane` but i am choosing panels inside this tabbedpane
what i need is when i move to a specific panel which is "cashier panel" is always to set focus on a certain textfield
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set a focus on Textfield in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425392/how-do-you-set-a-focus-on-textfield-in-swing)

Comment: i tried this but when i choose another panel then go back to the desired panel which is cashier panel there is no focus on the textfeild that i need.

Comment: hmmm add `addChangeListener` to your tabbedpane .then when tab selected/change check if active panel is cashier.if panel is cachier then call
`requestFocus()`

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: can you post a image of your gui with cashier panel ?

Comment: i need 10 reputation to post an image "stackoverflow conditions"

Comment: use imgurl and give the link.also you can post your codes

Comment: thanks for your help the code below solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void MainTabbedPaneStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {

        if(CashierPanel.isShowing()){
            Barcode_txt.requestFocus();
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also work,
when you specifying barcodeText's properties i.e. Height,Width etc set also focusable `true` as

```
barcodeText.setFocusable(true);
```